# How much water is needed using drip irrigation for Gold Mound hedge?

Tags: watering

Using drip irrigation, how long and how often should a gold mound hedge in Tampa, FL be watered during the the summer months?  Also, how often during the rest of the year?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is a bit vague: Without knowing how large your hedge is or anything about the soil properties, sun exposure etc. we could only wildly speculate and most likely be off by a good percentage... Could you specify? And remember: sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words...

Comment: "Gold mound" appears to be used for a few species: Duranta, Spirea, Sedum, Juniper. Please clarify which one you're talking about.

Comment: I assumed Gold Mound Spirea...how old are these plants?  Did you plant them?  Young plants newly planted will need regular watering until established 1-2 years.  Please send pictures...